# Extract classes from CSS selector using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing, css-selectors

Given a string representing a single CSS selector such as these (but ideally including any valid selector) how can I write a function to extract any classes used in the selector into an array? I would like do be able to do this outside the browser such as in node.js. The actual output I'm working with will come from the [`reap(tree).selectors`](https://github.com/ryanve/reap-css#usage) method but here are examples.

- parse `".example"` to `["example"]`
- parse `".example.state"` to `["example", "state"]`
- parse `"input[checked]"` to `[]`
- parse `".field:disabled .label"` to `["field", "label"]`
- parse `".flex\\@min-50em"` to `["flex\\@min-50em"]`
- parse `".flex-wrap.flex-reverse"` to `["flex-wrap", "flex-reverse"]`

The anwser should use a function like `function extractClasses(selector) {}` that returns an array. Or find an opensource npm package that does this in a reasonable reliable way.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: So, so far all you have for code is `function extractClasses(selector) {}`?  That code runs just fine, so I'm going to deduce that the problem is with the logic.  Specifically that there is none.  Try filling out the space between `{` and `}`.  If you get stuck, feel free to post a question about that specific issue. Otherwise, please don't consider stack overflow to be a free code writing service.

Comment: Shouldn't the string `".flex\\@min-50em"` return `["flex@min-50em"]` and not `["flex\\@min-50em"]`?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Emmet](https://docs.emmet.io/). Expand the string into a DOM Element, then read the classList.

For Node, use something like [js-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-dom) to create the element with Emmet.

Answer (score -1):

Well its easy, just have it split by . and spaces and delete any empty elements, and split : and return the first, here is what you should get:

```
function extractClasses(sel){
    var sel1=sel.split(".");
    var sel2=[];
    for(var i=0;i<sel1.length;i++){
        var sel3=sel1[i].split(" ");
        for(var i2=0;i2<sel3.length;i2++){
            var v=sel3[i2];
            if((v!="")&&(v.substr(0,"input".length)!="input")){
                if(v.replace(/\:/gim,"")!=v){v=v.split(":")[0];}
                sel2[sel2.length]=v;
            }
        }
    }
    return sel2;
}
```

Comment: This fails on `.flex\\@min-50em` by outputting `flex\@min-50em`.  Also, you shouldn't hard code `input` like that.  It'll just fail on any *other* selector like `h1` for instance, which outputs `h1`.

Comment: The ` \\\\ ` issue is due to ` \\ ` being an escape character, it escaped the char in front so you have to put ` \\\\\\\\ ` which translates to ` \\\\ `

Comment: what abount `[val="abc.def"]` ??

Comment: @PranavCBalan do you want it to return the value stuff?

Comment: @ModerateJavaScriptDev :  it should return an empty array since there is no class selector..